# How Microsoft planning to support Xamarin? Will we able to migrate existing Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android project to MAUI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I just came to know that Microsoft ending support to Xamarin and 1st May 2024 is the last date. They won't release any new major updates and will just provide support to their last release till May 1, 2024. And they will continue with their new product MAUI.

My concern is that, can we migrate our Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects to MAUI or do we have to start from scratch?

Comment: You cannot migrate Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS to MAUI. You can only migrate Xamarin.Forms projects to MAUI. You cannot even migrate Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS to Xamarin.Forms as they're quite different. You would need to reimplement your UI using XAML. What exactly are you dealing with? Xamarin.Forms or the old Xamarin without a shared UI implementation?

Comment: There's a migration guide in the official docs for Xamarin.Forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/migrate?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: My project is in Xamarin.iOS

Comment: Then you'll have to reimplement your UI, you may be able to reuse some business logic.

Comment: Would totally disagree with ewerspej, one can totally migrate native android or iOS projects to maui, targeting only one platform of interest. Go for it, do not fear my friend, you'll love maui.

Answer (score 1):

.NET MAUI is the successor to Xamarin.Forms specifically.

".NET for iOS" is the successor to Xamarin.iOS and ".NET for Android" is the successor to Xamarin.Android.

If you are currently using a Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android project (without Xamarin.Forms) you can migrate them to a new ".NET for iOS" or ".NET for Android" type project and keep most of the same code, with a few minor changes to your own codebase here and there (primarily namespace changes).

A very basic cproj file for a .NET for iOS project looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-ios</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

(Using .NET 8 in this example, but 6, 7 or any higher version should work as well)

A few notes on migration of libraries and NuGet packages:

- Xamarin.Android libraries/packages can be used in a .NET For Android project. It's backwards compatible.
- Xamarin.IOS libraries/packages can **NOT** be used in a .NET For iOS project. The creator of the library/package will have to update the package to support .NET for iOS (a lot of them have already done so)

**Migrating Xamarin.Essentials**

Xamarin.Essentials has been renamed Maui.Essentials. Despite the name, Maui is not required to use it and it can be used in non-MAUI .NET for iOS/.NET for Android projects.
It can be implemented in one of the following ways:

- Add the `UseMauiEssentials` flag to your project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-ios</TargetFramework>
        ...
        <UseMauiEssentials>true</UseMauiEssentials>
      </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

- Or add the Maui essentials nuget package to your project:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Essentials" Version="8.0.7" />`

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/upgrade-xamarin-ios-android-to-dotnet6-dotnet7/) is a blog post going in a bit more detail on the nuances of migrating from Xamarin to .NET for iOS/Android.

Answer (score 0):

As ewerspej said,  Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS are very different from .NET MAUI.

Microsoft will stop updating Xamarin by November 2022 and will use .NET MAUI only.  You need to read the MAUI docs and learn how to write MAUI apps. Maui is a cross-platform UI.  It’s a new implementation of your app.  Moving applications from Xamarin.Forms to .Net MAUI does not require rewriting the entire codebase. But you need to undertake a few code changes.

And these are related articles about how to migrate from Xamarin to MAUI, you can refer to them.

[Migrating from Xamarin.Forms (Preview).](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-from-Xamarin.Forms-(Preview)?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website)

[Xamarin.iOS Project -> now .NET MAUI iOS Project.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-from-Xamarin.Forms-(Preview)?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#step-1--csproj-files-updates)

[Migrating Xamarin.Android Applications to.NET 6.](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/Migrating-Xamarin.Android-Applications-to-.NET-6)

[Migrating from Xamarin.Android to.NET 7.](https://github.com/gmck/NavigationGraph6)

[Project file properties dotnet migration.](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki/Project-file-properties-dotnet-migration)

Comment: It's not required to rewrite Xamarin.iOS apps to MAUI apps. You can migrate them to ".NET 6 for iOS" using the same codebase with a few minor adjustments.